# Occurances of Num2 after Num1 in range(1,n) in Python with RECURSION

Tags: python, math, recursion, count, range

newbie here. I found on math.stackoverflow a question about how to count how many times 4 occurs after 3 in range 1 to 10000 (34, 340, but also 324, 3274). I wrote a code that solves it, but I was wondering if there is an easier and cleaner way to write it with recursion for *any number as n*.

```
def fours_after_threes(n):
    List = []
    for i in range(1,n,1):
        buf = ''
        buf += str(i)
        List.append(buf)

    cn = 0

    for el in List:
        if len(el) < 2:
            pass
        elif len(el) == 2:
            if el[0] == "3" and el[1] == "4":
                cn+=1

        elif len(el) == 3:
            if el[0] == "3" and el[1] == "4":
                cn+=1
            elif el[0] == "3" and el[2] == "4":
                cn+=1
            elif el[1] == "3" and el[2] == "4":
                cn+=1

        elif len(el) == 4:
            if el[0] == "3" and el[1] == "4":
                cn+=1
            elif el[0] == "3" and el[2] == "4":
                cn+=1
            elif el[0] == "3" and el[3] == "4":
                cn+=1
            elif el[1] == "3" and el[3] == "4":
                cn+=1
            elif el[1] == "3" and el[2] == "4":
                cn+=1
            elif el[2] == "3" and el[3] == "4":
                cn+=1

    return cn

print fours_after_threes(10000)


>>> 
523
```

That's the code that I'm stuck with. How to use "the rest" of the range? Or maybe you have an even better idea how to solve it for any given range and for any given numbers?

```
while len(List)>0:
    for el in List:
        if "3" in range(0,len(el)-1) and "4" in **range(1,...**
            cn+=1
            List.remove(List[0])
            return function_name(1000)
        else:
            List.remove(List[0])
            return function_name(1000)

print fours_after_threes(1,10000,3,4)
```

Comment: Why don't you just check `if '34' in str(i)`?

Comment: because he wants to count `324` as well?

Comment: Because it has to work for 304 and it can not work for 43.

Comment: @MSeifert -- Got it.  Sorry, I didn't understand that constraint.

Comment: Does `3434` count as 2?

Comment: @mgilson good question. Nobody mentioned that in the math.stackoverflow question. It would even count as three - 34xx, 3xx4, xx34.

All of the mathematicians wrote that the answer for this range is 523.

Comment: @mgilson It counts as one.

Comment: @TomWojcik -- Odd ... I get 524... assuming that `3434` counts as 2.

Comment: @mglison http://codepaste.net/2r8fhf

Comment: Ahh, if it counts as 1, then that makes sense.  Note, this is an easy problem to solve with regular expressions (2 lines of code).  I don't know if you are interested in a solution along those lines though . . .

Comment: I'm looking for problems to solve as a practice for my exam and I'm pretty sure that, as far as I know, my tutor wouldn't allow using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short function that returns True if there is a 3 before a 4 (digits = "34"), and number is also passed in as a string:

```
def in_string(digits, number):
    if not number:    # no more digits in number?
        return False  # all done
    digit = number[0]     # get the leading digit
    number = number[1:]   # leave the remaining digits in number
    if digit == digits[0]:    # found a digit in the sequence?
        digits = digits[1:]   # leave the remaining digits
        if not digits:        # no more digits in sequence?
            return True       # all done
    return in_string(digits, number)    # recursion

c = 0
for i in range(10000):
    if in_string("34", str(i)):
        c += 1
print c
```

The result is 523

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it with strings and splitting the string by the first occurence of a '3'. It's not as elegant as a regex example but it's clearly better than comparing each number of a string by hand.

```
def test(lst):
    counter = 0
    # Test every element of the list
    for i in lst:
        # Convert it to a string and split it by the *first* occurence of '3'
        i = str(i).split('3', 1)
        # Check if there was a 3 in it by comparing the length of the result
        if len(i) > 1:
            # Now check if a 4 is in the second part (meaning after the 3)
            if '4' in i[1]:
                counter += 1
    return counter

test(range(10000))
# returns 523
```

that's not with recursion but iterative. The expansion with different 'numbers' should be easy based on this example.

---

After some thinking I really found a way to do it recursive:

```
def test(lst, numbers):
    counter = 0
    for i in lst:
        # Start recursion for the current number and the numbers we are looking for
        counter += testnumber(str(i), numbers)
    return counter

def testnumber(number, remainingnumbers):
    if len(remainingnumbers) == 0:
        # No number remaining to look for - valid
        return 1
    if len(number) == 0:
        # Number is exhausted but we haven't found that combination
        return 0
    if number[0] == remainingnumbers[0]:
        # Check the rest of the number without the found first number
        # because we have found a match!
        return testnumber(number[1:], remainingnumbers[1:])
    else:
        # Check for the rest of the number... there was no match this recursion
        return testnumber(number[1:], remainingnumbers)

test(range(10000), ['3', '4'])
```

It can check arbitary combinations `['1', '2']` is also possible and even `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']` even though the latter one will result in a zero-count.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to make it with recursion.

Comment: Edited the answer - there is a recursive way of doing it ... even though it feels like not a good way.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
def rec(buffer_list, index, found):
    if index == len(buffer_list):
        return found
    num_str = str(buffer_list[index])
    three_index = -1
    four_index = -1
    if len(num_str) < 2:
        return rec(buffer_list, index+1, found)
    for i in num_str:
        if i == '3':
            three_index = num_str.index(i)
        if i == '4':
            four_index = num_str.index(i)

    if 0 <= three_index < four_index:
        found += 1
        return rec(buffer_list, index+1, found)
    else:
        return rec(buffer_list, index+1, found)


def find_three_four(n):
    found = 0
    numbers = range(1, n, 1)
    total = rec(numbers, 0, 0)
    print total

find_three_four(100)
```

Its not very elegant, but it seems to be working, gave 1 for the first 100 numbers (34), and 22 for 500. Python can't handle recursion with more than 999 calls, so keep that in mind when making recursion

Comment: Works great, thank you for pointing out this 999 limitation. As for me it seems to be working for over 999, but probably I misunderstood the code and there is one call after another.